# chrome open in other window

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say I have two Chrome windows open. When I click on a link in the first window, I want it to open that link in the second window. I don't want the link to open in a new window; I want the link to open in the already-opened second window. Is there a script/add-on that can do this?

EDIT: I'm aware you can drag the link to the second window, but I'm looking for a way to automate this (that is, changing the left-click to do this task)

Comment: Not quite an answer, but Chrome already works this way with Incognito Windows. Right-click a link & open in incognito window. A new incognito window opens. Right-click a second link (in the original window) and open in an incognito window. The incognito window created from the first link opens a new tab for the second link.

Comment: That's odd how that doesn't work for non-incognito mode. Could it a bug? I think I can live with this. Thanks!